# SQL Informix query Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, informix

I want my table group by month

I have a simple SQL Informix query like this :

**SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(startdatetime) 
FROM agentconnectiondetail 
WHERE WEEKDAY(startdatetime) IN (1,5) 
      GROUP BY MONTH(startdatetime)";
```

the output is :

> ERROR [42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.

what's wrong with my query ??

Comment: Is the `"` double quote really there like that? If so, that's the problem.  It also looks like you're only going to collect Mondays and Fridays data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the results grouped by month, you'll need to include that in the `SELECT` list. Your `GROUP BY` will need to use ordinal position style syntax, since you're grouping by an expression:

```
SELECT MONTH(startdatetime), COUNT(*)
  FROM agentconnectiondetail
  WHERE WEEKDAY(startdatetime) IN (1,5)
GROUP BY 1
```

Presumably you know what you're doing with the months from this year vs last year...

Answer (score 0):

Write only 
Group by startdatetime

Comment: I want my table's GROUP BY month